# Return two objects in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I am using nodejs with expressjs. I am making an ajax call that queries a job table for multiple jobs and also each job's corresponding Customer table. Individually I get two arrays' of objects. I populate the second array by iterating through the selected jobs' Customer ID like.

```
    for(var i=0; i<jobs.length; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<customerList.length; j++) {
            if (customerList[j].ID == jobs[i].CustomerID) {             
                   customerRecords.push(customerList[j]);   
            }
    }
```

What I am left with is two arrays of objects - 1. jobs 2. customerRecords. I have tried in many different forms to return these two objects to my view with as many variations of res.send(object/objects) that I could think of with no success. After googling, from what I read by a similar post I can only return one object with my ajax call? Is this true? how do I return both of these arrays of objects to my view?

-on standby, thank you for any help.

Comment: why dont you create a new object with both the array of objects and return that?

Comment: I don't know what you found on google, but that page meant that one ajax request can have one response (under usual circumstances). Your ajax response can be a JSON object with both the required objects as attributes of the main object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After googling, from what I read by a similar post I can only return one object with my ajax call? Is this true? how do I return both of these arrays of objects to my view?

Yes and no.
Of course, you could only have *one* result. But you could add both:

```
{
    customerList:[],
    jobs:[]
}
```

So in effect: two arrays in one object.
After you got the data: `result.customerList` (assuming you saved the outcome in an object named »result«) gives you the customerlist (as expected).

Answer (score 1):

You simply put them both in another object. Either:

```
{
  "array1" : [1,2],
  "array2" : [3,4]
}
```

or

```
[
  [1,2],
  [3,4]
]
```